# Cannot Check In to TFS with WebStorm

Tags: tfs, version-control, webstorm

I've been trying to get TFS (using TFS 2015) to integrate with WebStorm for some time now.  I followed [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/using-tfs-integration.html) to set it up, and I found/installed the plugin it mentions, successfully found and connected to my TFS servers, and pulled down the project flawlessly. However, I cannot seem to get the files to commit.  When I change a file, it will turn blue [like the documentation says it should](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/file-status-highlights.html), and if I right click on the file and go to:

```
TFS > Compare With The Same Repository Version
```

It correctly shows all the differences.  However, when I try to check in the file, I will always get a alert box saying "No changes detected", despite the fact that it JUST correctly showed me all my changes when I compared it to the repo version. There is one other persistent error message "Error updating changes: Read timed out" is always displayed for me under `Version Control: > Local Changes`.

In summary:

I followed the JetBrains documentation and [integrated TFS to WebStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdoqm.png).  I managed to pull the code I wanted to from my TFS 2015 server and seemingly all the items listed under [TFS Support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/using-tfs-integration.html#d1404e48) are working properly BESIDES modifications being shown and the ability to commit.

WebStorm can detect changes successfully [if I compare with the repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Mu0.png).

Despite this, when I try to commit [I am told that there are no changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVlwJ.png).

Comment: Please check that your Git root is registered in Settings | Version Control. Please refer to this case: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206176849-Git-Commit-says-no-changed-detected

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT This is an issue with TFS, not Git.  The same principle still applies however, so yes, I can confirm that the TFS project is registered in under Settings | Version Control

Comment: You're using TFVC version control not Git in TFS?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT Yes, sorry I guess I should have made that more clear.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer bro, maybe you solved the problem ..?